# Как отправить нормальный payload на сайт через requests?

Tags: python-3.x, json

```
url = 'https://www.carousell.com.hk/ds/search/cf/4.0/search/?_path=%2Fcf%2F4.0%2Fsearch%2F'
```

[image: Вот что прилетает с данного запроса из браузера!]

```
payload = {
    "bestMatchEnabled": "true",
    "canChangeKeyword": "false",
    "ccid": "561",
    "count": "48",
    "countryCode": '"HK"',
    "countryId": '"1819730"',
    "filters": [{ "enforce": "false", "fieldName": "collections", "idsOrKeywords": { "value": [ "462" ] } } ],
    "includeEducationBanner": "true",
    "includeSuggestions": "false",
    "locale": '"zh-Hant-TW"',
    "prefill": "{}",
    "query": "null",
    "searchContext": "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",
    "session": "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"
}

req = requests.post(url, data=payload, proxies=proxies)
```

`print(req)` - выводит <Response [422]>
`print(req.text)` - вообще ничего не выводит.
Не знаю как правильно вставить payload в запрос.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас типы значений не совпадают. Вы все значения делаете str, хотя не все из них должны быть str судя по запросу. В документации модуля requests почему-то нет ни слова об этом. Есть лишь пример, в котором в качестве ключа передается не строка, а кортеж и массив:

```
payload_tuples = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key1', 'value2')]
r1 = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=payload_tuples)
payload_dict = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2']}
r2 = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data=payload_dict)
print(r1.text)
```

Соответственно, у вас должно быть что-то вроде

```
payload = {
   "bestMatchEnabled": True,
   "canChangeKeyword": False,
   "ccid": 561,
   "count": 48,
   "countryCode": "HK",
   ...
}
```